# C# Разделить массив байт без выделения памяти

Tags: c#, массивы, выделение-памяти

Есть `readonly byte[]`, необходимо разделить его на два массива без выделения новой памяти. Как я сделал бы это на С++:
Создал один пойнтер на начало массива с размерностью в половину исходного.
Создал второй пойнтер с оффсетом в размерность предыдущего и размерностью до конца исходного.
Всё, я просто переразметил память без перезаписи и выделения новой. Примерно так:

```
    public unsafe void Divide(ref byte[] data, out byte[] secondHalf)
    {
        byte* fistHalf   = byte[data.Length / 2];
        byte* secondHalf = byte[data.Length / 2];
        fistHalf   = &data;
        secondHalf = &data + data.Length / 2;
    }
```

(очень приближённо, я ещё не понял, как указатели работают в C#)

Как это сделать в С# мне не очевидно совсем. Нашёл, что в С# тоже можно работать с указателями в unsafe, но это мове тон.

Comment: ReadOnlySpan, Span — посмотрите документацию. если проводить аналогию с C++, то это "управляемый pointer" + length. "управляемый pointer" в реализации CLR это просто pointer, только при GC он смещается на необходимый offset.

Comment: @return, почитал. Т.е. я правильно понял, что span.Slice() мне вернёт не новый массив, а ссылку на кусок того же? И его можно будет преобразовать обратно в byte[]?

Comment: [ArraySegment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?view=net-5.0)

Comment: да, вы правы, вам вернется "срез" массива без создания нового

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ArraySegment выглядит после релиза Span'ов немного устаревшим

Comment: На английском SO нашёл разъяснение разницы Span и ArraySegment. На случай, если кто-то будет читать этот тред с похожей проблемой.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020894/how-is-the-new-c-sharp-spant-different-from-arraysegmentt

Comment: `ArraySegment` больше похож на `Memory`. Если вы зайдете на github, то вы поймете, что это одно и тоже. только Memory может получать данные не только с массива, но и из строк, а также с `MemoryManager`

Comment: это делается обёрткой в `object`

Comment: @return - я согласен. Упомянул его лишь для полноты картины. Сейчас лучше исползовать спаны.

Comment: также дополню, что во .NET Framework "этих всяких" спанов нет, а ArraySegment не распространён ;)

Comment: @return, в документации написано, что span.ToArray() -- "Copies the content of this span to the new array", копирует в новый массив. Т.е. получается, чтобы получить массив, всё равно придётся создать новый и выделить память? :D

UPD:
Просто я же не могу отправить Span во внешнюю функцию, которая у меня принимает только byte[] array (речь об отправке по сети, ByteArrayContent : System.Net.Http.HttpContent)

Comment: @CorvusCorax: Ну да. Массив в C# — это не просто сырой кусок памяти, поэтому вы не сможете массив «проинтерпретировать» как два других массива. Работайте со `Span`'ами.

Comment: `*` - это указатель. `ref` и `out` - ссылки. Ссылки и указатели - разные сущности, они не взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Разделить массив байт без выделения памяти

Это невозможно, но без этого можно прекрасно обойтись.

Массив - это некий класс в памяти, который помимо данных содержит еще информацию о длине массива, типе хранимых данных и другую служебную информацию. Вы хотите из одного класса экземпляра класса получить два, при этом чтобы данные остались на месте. Но ведь в месте разделения данных надо записать служебную информацию для второго массива, что в любом случае приведет к копированию данных.

Далее, о том, где взять память для храния данных в C# решает Garbage Collector. Он хорошо оптимизирован, и ему стоит доверять в плане выделения и освобождения памяти.

Для ручной работы с памятью есть `unsafe` код, и он кстати - не моветон, его просто не стоит использовать без причины, так как это может ухудшить поддерживаемость кода, да и смысл наличия GC при этом теряется. Но бывают случаи, когда `unsafe` реально оправдан, например при использовании векторных вычислений (intrinsics), хотя разработчики .NET извернулись и здесь, и вполне можно обойтись без `unsafe` без потерь в производительности, хоть и не во всех ситуациях.

---

Если ваша задача в том, чтобы обрабатывать массив по частям, то подойдет решение ниже.

Во-первых, писать байты в служебную область массива вам не позволит CLR, потому что она бережно защищает ваши данные и память от повреждения. Как можно выехать из данной ситуации.

К примеру у вас есть массив байт.

```cs
byte[] data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray(); // [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

И вы хотите обработать сначала первую часть этого массива, потом вторую и при этом не копируя данные. Метод стар как мир.

```cs
private void DoSomething(byte[] array, int start, int length)
{
   for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++)
   {
       array[i] = array[i] * 2;
   }
}
```

И вызвать

```cs
DoSomething(data, 0, 5);
DoSomething(data, 5, 5);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", data)); // 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18
```

То есть вызываемый метод вносит изменения прямо в оригинальный массив, а не вкакую-то свою копию. Обратите внимание, я даже `ref` не использую.

Никаких указателей не требуется, так как массив - это и есть ссылка на данные в куче. Никакого копирования данных при выполнении выше указанного кода не произойдет.

Кстати, `ref` - это для значимых типов имеет смысл. Значимая часть в массиве - это сама ссылка на массив, то есть переменная, которая на него ссылается.

Comment: "информацию о типе хранимых данных" — неточность. т.к. массив — класс, то в заголовке хранится тип объекта. в случае с массивом это будет, например, `int[]`. т.е. тип хранимых данных не храниться в заголовке напрямую, но хранится в типе массива, реализующего template.

Comment: @return верно, но я не знаю, как это перефразировать лучше.

Comment: может, "..., типе массива"? человек, как я вижу, понимающий

Comment: также проблема у человека, как видно из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251199/c-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8/1251225?noredirect=1#comment2197733_1251206), не в копировании, а в трате памяти на создание нового массива в куче. думаю, упомянуть `ArrayPool`/`MemoryPool` не будет лишним

Comment: @return как отправить данные во внешний метод без создания нового массива я как раз и показал выше в решении. Этот массив всего-лишь надо создать во внешнем методе. Пулинг массивов - хорошо, но я пока не вижу намека на потребность в  нем в вопросе, так что не буду гадать. Если попросят - расскажем, но нужен конкретный, а не гипотетический сценарий.

Comment: дело в том, что вы выделяете массив по факту через `new`. это не совсем оптимально. но даже если учесть, что это пример, то не понятно, откуда этот массив брать. мне кажется, что это главный вопрос автора.

Comment: хотя, если данные фиксированного размера, то можно и `[ThreadLocal] static readonly byte[] data = ...;` использовать

Comment: @return вот когда автор расскажет, чтобы можно было без "кажется" утверждать, что ему нужно, тогда и будет конкретное решение. А пока, еще раз скажу, я не хочу гадать. Вопрос содержит XY-проблему.

Comment: Эта XY-проблема всегда вылетает из головы. Нет у меня на её "инстинкта" — справедливое замечание.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь Span. примерно так:

```
    int[] data = new int[]
{
    //
};
Span<int> spanFromData = data;
 
Span<int> first = spanFromData.Slice(0, 10);    
Span<int> last = spanFromData.Slice(10, 20);
```

В этом случае не будет выделения памяти.
ReadOnlySpan предназначен для неизменяющихся данных

Comment: В документации написано, что span.ToArray() -- "Copies the content of this span to the new array", копирует в новый массив. Т.е. получается, чтобы получить именно массив байтов, всё равно придётся создать новый и выделить память? :D UPD: Просто я же не могу отправить Span во внешнюю функцию, которая у меня принимает только byte[] array (речь об отправке по сети, ByteArrayContent : System.Net.Http.HttpContent)

Comment: @CorvusCorax да, это проблема .NET с пережитками .NET Framework и всеми этими `byte[]` вместо `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`, а в словарях, будьте добры, используйте `string` в качестве ключа. это очень бесит. Вы можете использовать ArrayPool/MemoryPool, чтобы можно было не выделять 100500 массивов

Comment: Раз уж использовать модные спаны, то по-модному `Span<int> first = spanFromData[0..10];`